# lastquarter, previousquarter and prioryear - PowerShell Functions

Tags: powershell

I am running below to get

@lastquarter - SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 23 - Returns  2021-12-31 00:00:00.000
@previousquarter -  SELECT DATEADD(qq, -1,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))), 23 - Returns 2022-12-31 00:00:00.000
@prioryear - SELECT DATEADD(yy, -1,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))), 23; - Returns 2022-09-30 00:00:00.000

How would I write this in Powershell to get above?

Does it have any functions I can use. I looked into get-date but it seemes getting above in PowerShell is not as straightforward

Would appreciate some assistance with building up the logic in PS

Comment: Can you describe the calculations in words? I’m going a bit cross-eyed trying to understand all the nested DATEADD / DATEDIFF calls :-). Some examples would be useful as well…

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response.  
lastquarter is a bit like this month - 3 month and last day of that month. 
previousquarter is this month - 6 and last day of that month--- 
prioryear  will be this month - 12 and last day of that month.

 For example if today is 12 jan 2022, 
lastquarter  2022-12-30  , 
previousquarte -  2022-09-30    and   
prioryear 2021-12-31

Answer (score 0):

Here's some expressions that give the values you're after. I've not tested them extensively, so you might want to write some Pester tests or something to validate them with edge cases, etc...

It also assumes you don't care about the time part - you might need to clear that in the `$quarterStart` expression if that matters...

```
$timestamp = [datetime] "2022-01-12";
write-host "timestamp = $timestamp";
# timestamp = 01/12/2022 00:00:00

# find the start of the *current* quarter - it's easier and
# clearer to work out the others from this interim value
$quarterStart = $timestamp.AddDays(-$timestamp.Day + 1).AddMonths(-($timestamp.Month-1) % 3);
write-host "quarter start = $quarterStart";
# quarter start = 01/01/2022 00:00:00

# end of the quarter before the current one
# (i.e. one day before the current quarter start)
$lastQuarter = $quarterStart.AddDays(-1);
write-host "last quarter = $lastQuarter";
# last quarter = 12/31/2021 00:00:00

# end of the quarter before the last one
# (i.e. three months and one day before the current quarter start)
$previousQuarter = $quarterStart.AddMonths(-3).AddDays(-1);
write-host "previous quarter = $previousQuarter";
# previous quarter = 09/30/2021 00:00:00

# end of the previous year
# (i.e. 31st December of the previous year)
$lastYear = new-object DateTime(($timestamp.Year - 1), 12, 31);
write-host "last year = $lastYear";
# last year = 12/31/2021 00:00:00
```